# Value in JSON Object not being accessed

Tags: android, null, json

I have JSON Object `contacts` which Looks like so `{"email":"Mark@HookahStationBCS.com","phone":"+19796918899"}`In my code I grab the `phone` key and am able to get it's value, but then when I print out the `email` value it says it's null, and in my code below it doesn't actually pass the termination case. Does anyone know why?

```
if(nextActivityObject.getJSONObject("contacts") != null){
    Log.d("NEXT ACTIVITY OBJECT NOT EMPTY", "NOT EMPTY");
    contacts = nextActivityObject.getJSONObject("contacts");
    if(contacts.getString("phone") != null){

        phone = contacts.getString("phone");
        Log.d("PHONE PASSED", phone.toString());
        intent.putExtra("phone",phone);
    } else if(contacts.getString("email") != null){
          email = contacts.getString("email");
          Log.d("THIS IS THE EMAIL PASS", email.toString());
          intent.putExtra("email", email);
       }
 }
```

Comment: You need to get both the email and phone, right? because in your code it seems you get the email only if the phone is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code should be something like this:

```
if (nextActivityObject.getJSONObject("contacts") != null){

    Log.d("NEXT ACTIVITY OBJECT NOT EMPTY", "NOT EMPTY");
    contacts = nextActivityObject.getJSONObject("contacts");

    if(contacts.getString("phone") != null && contacts.getString("email") != null){

       phone = contacts.getString("phone");
       email = contacts.getString("email");

       intent.putExtra("phone",phone);
       intent.putExtra("email",email);

     } 
     else if (contacts.getString("phone") != null){

              phone= contacts.getString("phone");
              intent.putExtra("phone", phone);
     }
     else if (contacts.getString("email") != null){

              email = contacts.getString("email");
              intent.putExtra("email", email);
     }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have an elseif condition.. You have to have 2 if conditions. I am pretty much saying what the previous poster said, just wording it differently.